# VBA code to add cell programatically

Tags: vba, excel

Hi and Thank as well as sorry for asking such a newbie question
How do I create a VBA code for adding A1 + B1 = C1 then next row which is A2 + B2 = C2 then so on and so forth.
Please help me. I know how to create formulas but this one i dont know.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Just a simple macro is all I ned.

Here's had came up but to no avail.

```
Worksheets("Total").Activate
Set MyRange = Range("H3:H100")
For Each mycell in MyRange
H3 = A3+B3+C3
(so if the next loop it will look like H4 = A4+B4+C4 and so on)
Next mycell
End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any loop here. There is more efficient way:

```
With Worksheets("Total").Range("H3:H100")
    .Formula = "=A3+B3+C3" ' or "=SUM(A3:C3)"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

**Explanation:**

**1)** line `.Formula = "=A3+B3+C3"` writes formula in each cell. Excel automatically adjust this formula for each row:

- in `H3` formula would be `=A3+B3+C3`
- in `H4` formula would be `=A4+B4+C4`
- .....................
- in `H100` formula would be `=A100+B100+C100`

You can also use this formula instead: `.Formula = "=SUM(A3:C3)"` - result would be the same.

**2)** line `.Value = .Value` rewrites formulae with their result values. If you want to leave formulae, you can remove this line.

---

If you're still interesting how to do the same thing using loop, look at the following code:

```
Dim MyRange As Range, c As Range

With Worksheets("Total")
    Set MyRange = .Range("H3:H100")
    For Each c In MyRange
        c.Value = .Range("A" & c.Row) + .Range("B" & c.Row) + .Range("C" & c.Row)
    Next mycell
End With
```

code above loops through each cell in range `H3:H100` and calculates sum of corresponding values from columns `A`,`B`,`C`.
You can see how I do it here: `.Range("A" & c.Row)`. Here `c.Row` returns row number of "current" cell in range `H3:H100` and `"A" & c.Row` gives you `A3` when `c` referce to `H3`, `A4` - when `c` referce to `H4` and so on.

---

You may also want to read this: [How to avoid using Select/Active statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)